# Java send udp packet to dns server

Tags: java, dns, udp, client

I am trying to send udp packet to specified dns server and receive a respone from dns server.

The problems is that I don't dont get the response from the server. I trying to receive a packet with my client socket but don't have any success.

Looking for help to fix this problem.

This is my UdpClient.java

```
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.Scanner;

class UdpClient
{
    public static void main (String args[]) throws Exception
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a hostname: ");
        // host name
        String hostname = scan.next();
        // socket
        DatagramSocket clientSocket = new DatagramSocket();
        InetAddress ipAddress = InetAddress.getByName(hostname);
        String message = "0471001000000";
        byte[] data = message.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

        // datagram packet
        DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length, ipAddress, 53);
        // send the packet
        clientSocket.send(sendPacket);
        // set a receive timeout, 2000 milliseconds
        // packet for receive
        byte[] rdata = new byte[1024];
        DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(rdata, rdata.length, ipAddress, 53);
        // wait for a response from the server
        clientSocket.receive(receivePacket);
        System.out.println("Host Name: " + ipAddress.getHostName());
        System.out.println("Canonical Host Name: " + ipAddress.getCanonicalHostName());
        System.out.println("Local Host: " + ipAddress.getLocalHost());
        System.out.println("Loopback Address: " + ipAddress.getLoopbackAddress());
        System.out.println("IPv4: " + ipAddress.getHostAddress());
        String serverMessage = new String(receivePacket.getData(), 0, receivePacket.getLength());
        System.out.println("FROM SERVER: " + serverMessage);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you verify the server is receiving the packet?

Comment: How can I verify this?

For example, when I enter "google.com" the program is waiting at line clientSocket.receive(reicePacket) and does nothing.

Comment: My mistake. I assumed it was a local server.

Comment: The remote name server expects you to send DNS wireformat to it. Java is not my language, but it looks like you're not doing that. So my guess is that your UDP packet get to the server just fine, but that the server considers its unparseable garbage and ignores it.

Comment: @PauliusAleksiūnas I think my answer below should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 22):

Here is a quick and dirty example of querying a DNS record via UDP and printing the result:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;

/**
 * A quick and dirty example of query DNS A record and log response.
 * This code has no error handling.
 *
 */

public class DNSClient {
    private static final String DNS_SERVER_ADDRESS = "8.8.8.8";
    private static final int DNS_SERVER_PORT = 53;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String domain = "google.com";
        InetAddress ipAddress = InetAddress.getByName(DNS_SERVER_ADDRESS);

        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(baos);

        // *** Build a DNS Request Frame ****

        // Identifier: A 16-bit identification field generated by the device that creates the DNS query. 
        // It is copied by the server into the response, so it can be used by that device to match that 
        // query to the corresponding reply received from a DNS server. This is used in a manner similar 
        // to how the Identifier field is used in many of the ICMP message types.
        dos.writeShort(0x1234);

        // Write Query Flags
        dos.writeShort(0x0100);

        // Question Count: Specifies the number of questions in the Question section of the message.
        dos.writeShort(0x0001);

        // Answer Record Count: Specifies the number of resource records in the Answer section of the message.
        dos.writeShort(0x0000);

        // Authority Record Count: Specifies the number of resource records in the Authority section of 
        // the message. (“NS” stands for “name server”)
        dos.writeShort(0x0000);

        // Additional Record Count: Specifies the number of resource records in the Additional section of the message.
        dos.writeShort(0x0000);

        String[] domainParts = domain.split("\\.");
        System.out.println(domain + " has " + domainParts.length + " parts");

        for (int i = 0; i<domainParts.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Writing: " + domainParts[i]);
            byte[] domainBytes = domainParts[i].getBytes("UTF-8");
            dos.writeByte(domainBytes.length);
            dos.write(domainBytes);
        }

        // No more parts
        dos.writeByte(0x00);

        // Type 0x01 = A (Host Request)
        dos.writeShort(0x0001);

        // Class 0x01 = IN
        dos.writeShort(0x0001);

        byte[] dnsFrame = baos.toByteArray();

        System.out.println("Sending: " + dnsFrame.length + " bytes");
        for (int i =0; i< dnsFrame.length; i++) {
            System.out.print("0x" + String.format("%x", dnsFrame[i]) + " " );
        }

        // *** Send DNS Request Frame ***
        DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();
        DatagramPacket dnsReqPacket = new DatagramPacket(dnsFrame, dnsFrame.length, ipAddress, DNS_SERVER_PORT);
        socket.send(dnsReqPacket);

        // Await response from DNS server
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
        socket.receive(packet);

        System.out.println("\n\nReceived: " + packet.getLength() + " bytes");

        for (int i = 0; i < packet.getLength(); i++) {
            System.out.print(" 0x" + String.format("%x", buf[i]) + " " );
        }
        System.out.println("\n");


        DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(buf));
        System.out.println("Transaction ID: 0x" + String.format("%x", din.readShort()));
        System.out.println("Flags: 0x" + String.format("%x", din.readShort()));
        System.out.println("Questions: 0x" + String.format("%x", din.readShort()));
        System.out.println("Answers RRs: 0x" + String.format("%x", din.readShort()));
        System.out.println("Authority RRs: 0x" + String.format("%x", din.readShort()));
        System.out.println("Additional RRs: 0x" + String.format("%x", din.readShort()));

        int recLen = 0;
        while ((recLen = din.readByte()) > 0) {
            byte[] record = new byte[recLen];

            for (int i = 0; i < recLen; i++) {
                record[i] = din.readByte();
            }

            System.out.println("Record: " + new String(record, "UTF-8"));
        }

        System.out.println("Record Type: 0x" + String.format("%x", din.readShort()));
        System.out.println("Class: 0x" + String.format("%x", din.readShort()));

        System.out.println("Field: 0x" + String.format("%x", din.readShort()));
        System.out.println("Type: 0x" + String.format("%x", din.readShort()));
        System.out.println("Class: 0x" + String.format("%x", din.readShort()));
        System.out.println("TTL: 0x" + String.format("%x", din.readInt()));

        short addrLen = din.readShort();
        System.out.println("Len: 0x" + String.format("%x", addrLen));

        System.out.print("Address: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < addrLen; i++ ) {
            System.out.print("" + String.format("%d", (din.readByte() & 0xFF)) + ".");
        }
    }

}
```